# Why there are tomboy but no Tomgirls?

Tags: gender

Tomboys are girls who behave like men but most of them are not transgender and lesbian.

But why there are no tomgirls, boys who behave like girls but are not transgender and homosexual?

What is the the reason?

Comment: They definitely do exist, I personally know a few who are not transgender/homosexual and still have "feminine traits or characteristics" of sorts.

Comment: maybe this question should be re-asked in linguistic board?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Who said there aren't? Tomgirl isn't the term used, but I am sure there are straight men who have feminine traits out there. I think this is called **effeminacy**. Here's the Wikipedia link for that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effeminacy.